# Problem appending CSV upload to existing BigQuery table

Tags: google-bigquery

I've been used to quickly uploading a CSV file to append data to an **existing** table in BigQuery.

I've made the new table name the same as the existing table, and I've then had options to overwrite or append data to the existing table.

This seems to have changed in the past few days and there is a new BigQuery console UI.

When I try and create a new table from a CSV file upload, under the table name field it currently says:

> Unicode letters, marks, numbers, connectors, dashes or spaces allowed.
> The job will create the specified destination table if needed, or the
> table must be empty **if it already exists**.

[image]

However, when I try and create a table with the same name as an existing table (even though the existing table is empty), I get a red warning saying:

> Table already exists

[image]

Does anyone know if this feature has now been removed or how to easily append data?

The long way round is to upload a CSV to a new table, then query the new table and set the destination to append or overwrite an existing table. Not ideal, particulalry having to define a new table schema.

Answer (score 8):

In order to append a CSV file to an existing BigQuery table when using the Console, please follow the instructions below:

1. In the **Explorer** panel, expand your project and select a dataset.
2. Expand the **Actions** option and click **Open**.
3. In the details panel, click **Create table**.
4. On the **Create table** page, in the **Source** section:

   - For **Create table from**, select Upload.
   - Browse file from system
5. On the **Create table** page, in the **Destination** section:

   - For **Dataset name**, choose the appropriate dataset.
6. In the **Schema** section, for **Auto detect**, check **Schema and input parameters** to enable schema [auto detection](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schema-detect). Alternatively, you can manually enter the [schema](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas) definition
7. Click **Advanced options**.

   - For **Write preference**, choose **Append to table**

Please review [this document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#appending_to_or_overwriting_a_table_with_csv_data) that expands on the same topic.

Comment: Thanks for this. It's the workflow I'm used to, but not what was showing earlier today (as per my screengrabs). I've tried it again and it looks like BigQuery Console has been rolled back to the previous UI and it's now working again.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this -- that seems really counter-intuitive to me. But it makes sense now that I know.